# How to bind ["alt+f,n"] in sublime on mac?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

I'm trying to bind <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> key sequence to a specific command. It only inserts an `ƒ` character, however.

```
[
  { "keys": ["alt+f,n"], "command": "advanced_new_file_new"}
]
```

How do I bind it correctly so that when I click alt+f and then n the command is executed?

Btw, if I change the binding to just `["alt+f"]` the binding works, it's not what I want though.

EDIT:
sublime console says:

```
Unable to parse binding {command: advanced_new_file_new, keys: [alt+f,n]}
```

investigating further to understand why this is invalid..

Comment: Did you try changing the , to a + as in alt+f+n ?

Comment: **Note: (added 2023-02-17)** Some content in this thread may reference stale links to the SublimeText docs. Readers may experience better results by replacing **BEFORE** [http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest) with **AFTER** [https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide](https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide). Also known as: "Sublime Text Community Documentation"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.. problem was I was looking into old sublime text documentation, which uses xml for key bindings. Sublime 3 uses json.

**All I had to do was change this:**

```
[
  { "keys": ["alt+f,n"], "command": "advanced_new_file_new"}
]
```

**to this:**

```
[
  { "keys": ["alt+f","n"], "command": "advanced_new_file_new"}
]
```

docs: http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/key_bindings.html

Comment: Just as a note, XML was used in ST1. Both ST2 and ST3 use json files. People have requested jon remove or add some version information to those pages, but he has not.